# React setState within Promise.all

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, promise

I'm working on a project where we would like run multiple fetches in parallel to a very slow API. Ideally, we would like to populate our interface for the user as this data is received and do so in a summative manner. These requests may or may not resolve in the order that the API calls were made.

Most use cases of `Promise.all` with a setState involve setting state after all promises have resolved. However, what I'm looking to do demands setting state as a side effect within the child promises themselves, I believe.

So this is (simplified) what I am doing to achieve this:

```
  const request = async (setState, endpoint) => {
    const response = await fetch(endpoint);
    const data = response.json();
    setState(state => ({ ...state, ...data }))
  }

  // Called within React component as a side effect
  const fetchAllData = (setState) => {
    Promise.all(
      [
        request(setState, url_1),
        request(setState, url_2),
        request(setState, url_3)
      ]
    )
  }
```

Now, I'm running some testing and this *does appear to work*. I believe I should not be running into race conditions with the state because setState is being passed a function. However, I do wonder if I'm doing something dangerous with respect to React, updating state, and rendering.

Is there anything wrong with this picture?

Comment: Looks fine, though Promise.all is having no effect here. Just call `request` 3 times (without awaiting the result), and delete the surrounding Promise.all.

Comment: @NicholasTower right, because Javascript will not wait for the promise to resolve before continuing to the next line! It's unusual for me to _not_ want promises to resolve before having the next line occur so I didn't even realize that.

Comment: I think that React 18 would make your life easier. You can make each request in the component that needs the data, and let Suspense show a loader while it's not ready. Check this demo that uses the SWR api library - https://swr.vercel.app/docs/suspense

Comment: I'm not really sure, but I suspect Promise.all will stop executing if one promise is rejected. In case you want to keep track of success and failure of the promises, maybe Promise.allSettled is worth looking into?

Comment: @GøranCantona that is true. I need to add error handling to the child function as well as one for the parent, and Promise.all may allow us to do that in an elegant way.

Comment: Do all your requests return distinct data (with different properties)? Otherwise the object spread syntax is probably not what you want, making it impossible to distinguish which value came from which response.

Comment: @Bergi thank you for the keen eye. The example code I posted is a simplification - just to show how I plan to get the new state value based on existing state - but you are correct that I will have some more complexity to the function to ensure the data is segregated and to ensure the data doesn't overwrite itself as it loads in.

Answer (score -1):

There's nothing wrong with immediately updating state from each individual promise; this will work just fine. You might have a race condition if every request attempts to update the same bit of data, but as long as they write different parts of your state you should be fine (the state updater callback pattern is necessary though).

The only thing wrong with your code is the missing error handling, and that the `Promise.all` is currently a bit superfluous.